# Button in cell.imageView frame

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I put a info button in the imageview frame reserved in uitableViewcell?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is create the button and add it to the cell:

```
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[infoButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,infoButton.frame.size.width, infoButton.frame.size.height)];
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:infoButton];
```

Edit---

As you want to use the imageView property of the cell, you are required to provide your own image and you need to set a gesture recogniser so that you know when the imageView has been tapped.

```
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info-button.png"]];
[cell.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(infoImageTapped:)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[cell.imageView setGestureRecognizers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tap]];
[tap release];

- (void) infoImageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) tap {
    //show info view.
}
```

Comment: But I want to show it in the left side of the cell. If I have some text the button appears above the text. I want to use the imageview property of the cell. Is that possible? Thanks!